# Is there a name for this type of boundary condition of the heat equation : u(x,0)==0, u(0,t) == F(t) leading to a general solution in terms of erfc?

Tags: heat-equation

In an earlier contribution "*The general solution to the heat equation*" from Apr 27, 2018 a solution to the heat equation in terms of erfc functions was obtained for the following boundary conditions **u(x,0)==0, u(0,t) == F(t)** (with F(t)= exp(lambda*t)). These boundary conditions do not fall into the well-know categories of Dirichlet, von Neumann or Robin boundary conditions. My question is whether there is a name for that type of boundary conditions.

Comment: $u(x,0)$ we call an "initial condition". $u(0,t)=f(t)$ we would call a Dirichlet boundary condition.

Comment: Also it's a **Neumann** boundary condition, not a von Neumann BC. Von Neumann and Neumann were two different mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks K.defaoite for clarification. R.K.